# What is wrong with this PHP/SQL code?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, sql-server

So I get no SQL errors or anything with this code, which basically inserts into the table 'nametable', it inserts info1 and info2, but it isn't inserting for some reason, please let me know what is wrong, thanks!

Code:

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1>Insert data</h1>
    <form action="insert.php" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="info1" /><br><br>
    Password: <input type="text" name="info2" /><br><br>

    <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("my ip","induadmi_main","my pw");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("induadmi_main", $con);

    $sql="INSERT INTO nametable (info1, info2)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[info1]','$_POST[info2]')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    echo "1 record added";

    mysql_close($con)
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

EDIT:
It turns out I DID have a SQL error
Could not connect: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'my IP' (4)

What am I supposed to put as my server? I tried my IP, my cpanel login username, my database name, nothing is working

thanks

Comment: Did,  Access denied for user 'induadmi_main'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Your code also has SQL injection vulnerabilities. You need to use the **`mysql_real_escape_string()`** function to wrap those user supplied values when they are included in the SQL text. Also, the mysql interface is deprecated; use the PDO or mysqli interface for new development.

Comment: @spencer7593 I am pretty new to SQL and PHP, I have no idea what you said

Comment: @Notheir That message says your username or password is wrong.

Comment: @Tim I just logged in fine, and I just changed pw to what I am using, just wondering, it's "localhost" then what, username? then "password

Comment: @Notheir See my answer below...

Comment: @Tim I just added the password, does it take time to update?

Comment: @Notheir No, it should be immediate. I've updated my answer with the correct sequence so you can see how it's supposed to be in your script.

Comment: @Notheir: reference documentation for **`mysql_real_escape_string`** function is here: [http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)  **"This function must always** (with few exceptions) **be used to make data safe before sending a query to MySQL."**

Comment: @Notheir So what solved your problem? chapman84's answer was the same as mine, but with more explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using variables in your mysql connect statement and not strings. The error statement shows that it errored out when it encountered 'my IP' and that tells you that is where the problem is.

If you are passing in variables to your mysql_connect statement it would look like:

```
$con = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
```

That is assuming the following:
$host = the host name of your connection (quite possibly the ip address of your host.
$username = the username of the mysql instance you are connecting to.
$password = the password for the instance you are connecting to.

Also if you are in the process of learning MySQL and PHP it is ***HIGHLY*** recommended that you learn to connect using the pdo or mysqli connection methods. The method you are using is deprecated and will not be supported moving forward.

Read the warning about deprecation and the connection documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: Thank you a TON @chapman84, I understand now, should be able to fix!

Comment: No problem, we all start at some point. If the answer helped you try to accept it as the correct answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

## Insert data

Username: 
    Password:

```
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("my ip","induadmi_main","my pw");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("cis_id", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO nametable (info1, info2)
VALUES
('".$_POST['fname'] . "','."$_POST['lname']."')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con)
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","YOUR-USERNAME","YOUR-PASSWORD");
```

Usually the server is going to be `localhost`. if that doesn't work, ask your hosting company what to put there.

Also, look into [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead of `mysql`, as mysql is depreciated.

full code...

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "YOUR-USERNAME", "YOUR-PASSWORD");
mysql_select_db("YOUR-DATABASE-NAME", $conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is your ip, have you tried it with the port you use?

```
<ip>:<port>
```

and check if your destination server/machine has blocked your access or not